# Start program as administrator on account without admin rights without typing password

Tags: windows, powershell

On of the labs on our campus has a program that requires elevated permissions to run. What I would like to do is find a way to allow only that specific program to start as admin without having to make the students type in a password. The reason being that I would rather the students not know the password to the local admin of the computer.

I have tried a few powershell scripts without much success (I am very new to powershell). What I was thinking is that if I could make a script to start the program as admin then the students could just start the script instead. I am open to any options though.

We run Win 7 Pro on these machines.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: And, is this a program that must be manually started? Or, can it be started when the machine starts?

Comment: This falls under the category of "when people ask for security holes as features." No, you can't do it. If it were possible, security would be pointless.

Comment: You may be able to use the [ACT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082.aspx) to make the program not require admin privlages depending on the reason it requires the privlages.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to, but try with Applocker.
You get applocker with windows.
Just google AppLocker.